# How to call a platform code from an isolate in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates, flutter-method-channel

I know these libraries [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) and [isolate_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/isolate_handler) exist that support doing these but I couldn't find any method to call platform specific codes from inside of them. Can someone show any example of how it's done ?

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this?

Comment: Sadly, I didn't @Chichebe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer might not answer to your question directly but I was facing the same situation.
I was working on this to run a computing intensive task avoiding UI lagging. After a long research, no, you cannot run Platform from other isolates rather than the main one.

Instead of making and running the native code on another isolate, **let's make the native code run in background instead** with `TaskQueue`.
[Channels and platform threading](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab#executing-channel-handlers-on-background-threads)

The example code in the above link is using `onAttachedToEngine`, you can check it out. However, I was using is `configureFlutterEngine` so I have to figure out a little bit until I found a solution that I need `binaryMessenger` to make it working. Luckily it can called from `flutterEngine` too!

This is the example code of when using `configureFlutterEngine`

```kotlin
class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {

    val MOBILE_SDK_CHANNEL = "com.example.app/flutter"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        val taskQueue = flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger.makeBackgroundTaskQueue()

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, MOBILE_SDK_CHANNEL,
                StandardMethodCodec.INSTANCE, taskQueue).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            // TODO : Do implementation here
            when (call.method) {
                "example_method" -> {
                    // success
                    // result.success(data)
                }
                else -> result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With `taskQueue` the native code will be ready to run in background.

```dart
Future<void> getData() async {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    const platform = MethodChannel("com.example.app/flutter");
    var data = await platform.invokeMethod("example_method");
    // data is ready to use and non-blocked the UI thread
    return data
  }
}
```

The native code now runs in non-blocking manner, no more UI lag. :)

Comment: This was insightful, will try to implement it and see how this works.

Comment: "make the native code run in background instead" that's the key and the solution. For Kotlin you can use `CoroutineScope` with `Dispatchers`.

Comment: For me it still doesn't work. I get the following exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method xxx on channel yyy). Looks like I have to make a plugin...

Comment: i get an MissingPluginException when using this